# Cocos2D Realistic Gravity?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gravity

I have tried many different techniques of applying a realistic looking gravity feature in my game but have had no luck so far. I plan on offering a *100 point bounty* on this for someone who can show me or (share) some code that applies gravity to a CCSprite in Cocos2D.

What I have done so far has just been ugly or unrealistic and I have asked in many different places on what the best approach is but I just have not found any good looking gravity techniques yet.

Anyway, can anyone offer some tips/ideas or their approach only applying gravity to a CCSprite in Cocos2D **without** using a physics engine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A effective approach without having to explicitly use any physics engine is to step the velocity and position of your sprite manually in your update loop. This is essentially Euler Integration.

```
// define your gravity value
#define GRAVITY -0.1

// define a velocity variable in the header of your Game class/CCSprite Subclass (neater)
float velocity_y;

-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
    // Step the y-velocity by your acceleration value (gravity value in this case)
    velocity_y += GRAVITY *dt; // drop the dt if you don't want to use it 

    // Step the position values and update the sprite position accordingly
    sprite.position.y += velocity_y* dt; // same here
}
```

In the code snippet above, I defined a velocity_y variable to keep track of my sprite's current velocity along the y-direction. Remember to initialize this value to 0 in your init method.

Next comes the crux of Euler. At every time step:

1. Advance your velocity by your acceleration (which is your gravity) multiplied by dt to find your new velocity.
2. Advance your position by your newly computed velocity value multiplied by dt to find your new position.

You can experiment whether using delta-time or not (see LearnCocos2D's excellent comment on the cons of using it) works for your game. While multiplying by delta-time allows your object motion to more accurately take into account varying framerates, as LearnCocos2d pointed out, it might be wise to avoid using it in a real-time game where system interrupts (new mail, low battery, ads pop-out) can occur and subsequently cause the game simulation to jump forward in an attempt to make up.

So if you are dropping the dt, remember to tweak (scale down) your GRAVITY value accordingly to retain the right feel, since this value is no longer multiplied by the value of delta-time (which is ~ 1/60).

Aditional Tip: To apply an impulse to move the sprite (say via a swipe), you can affect the velocities directly by changing the values of velocity_x (if you have this) and velocity_y.

I have used this approach in my games, and it works very well. hope it helps.

Comment: I like to add that this also works without multiplying with delta time. You may want to avoid delta time because any drop in framerate will keep the object moving at the same speed but the player must react to the changes more quickly, and may not be able to due to the lower framerate. There's also the side-effect if, for example, a background process blocks the CPU for 0.2 seconds, the simulation jumps forward by a large amount. Again that can easily kill the player because it's unexpected. Personally I prefer to slow down the entire game simulation as framerate drops by not using dt time.

Comment: @Kentoh Would you be able to edit your post so it includes the tips the LearnCocos2D gave? Your code looks great so far but I want it to be as bug-free as possible!

Comment: Also would you be able to show how you declared those variables in the .h and remove the velocity X since I only need the Y value? :P

Comment: Update: I added the bounty of 100 points. If @LearnCocos2D knows how to properly apply gravity, please feel free to add it as an answer!

Comment: @iBradApps, I have updated the answer. You can declare the velocity_y anywhere, even in the header of the game class, if you only have a single sprite that you want to apply gravity to. Otherwise, you might want to subclass CCSprite, and add it as a member, so that you can do mysprite.velocity_y for instance. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @kentoh, I will try this out later! Just one question, the gravity will increase over time just like in real life correct?

Comment: The gravity should be constant, just as it is in real life where everything accelerates at a gravitational value of 9.81m/s2 towards the earth. It's the velocity of the falling object that should  increase over time as a result of the constant acceleration. So keep it constant!

Comment: Okay thank you, last question. How would I reset the gravity properly in order to stop my sprite from falling? Lets say it collides with the floor, I need to stop the character from falling so how would I properly stop the gravity with your code?

Comment: Also I currently have implemented a fixed time step in my game so will it then be okay to use delta time since everything will be slowed down then?

Comment: Gravity should stay constant, even upon collision. What you should do is implement proper collision detection to compute new values for velocity_y, which might not be trivial, depending on the object shape. If the body can be treated as a sphere, and assuming an elastic collision, an easy impulse-based approach is to negate the value of your y-velocity upon contact (or reduce the velocity value if it's non-elastic).

Comment: My gravity does not have to be that in depth. 1) If I want to just have a simple method to reset the gravity. Can't I just do velocity_y = 0; ? 2) Also can I use delta time if I am using a fixed time step in my game, wouldn't that negate the cons that LearnCocos2D said?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't trivial matter, you should try to see other posts. I'm sure other poeple already had this issue. Try to look at :

- [How to simulate a gravity for one sprite in cocos2d without a physics engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162685/how-to-simulate-a-gravity-for-one-sprite-in-cocos2d-without-a-physics-engine)
- [Cocos2D Gravity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130808/cocos2d-gravity)

Or try our good friend google :

- http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/ -> got to *Math and Physics* and then *A Verlet based approach for 2D game physics*
- http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/

In any case here are some tips :

Step 1, calculate the effective direction vectors 
Step 2, calculate velocity
Step 3, project this velocity onto the two effective directions.
Step 4, generate an equal and opposite force for the two direction and call this the “response force”.